# How to configure _defaultOptions.headers in Angular 2 (extending Http class)

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest, content-type

I'm trying to set up the HEADERS for HXR request in order to have **"Content-Type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8"** for any ajax call I'll do, but I got several errors trying to extends Http class

```
import {Http, RequestOptions, ConnectionBackend} from "@angular/http";

export class HttpCustom extends Http{

    constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions){
        super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
        this._defaultOptions.headers.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to extend Http properly or even a different solution to set up HEADERS once?

Answer (score 0):

You can extended the merge method from RequestOptions class

```
export class AppRequestOptions extends RequestOptions {

  merge(options?:RequestOptionsArgs):RequestOptions {

    let headers = options.headers || new Headers;
    headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8';
    options.headers = headers;

    return super.merge(options);
  }
}
```

Then you provide your custom class in the app bootstrap

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
          HTTP_PROVIDERS,
          {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AppRequestOptions })
]);
```

It should be enough.

Comment: "provide" method is deprecated (RC4)... do you have any other idea to do it?

Comment: Then use the object version.
{provide: RequestOptions, useClass: AppRequestOptions }

Comment: Really wanted to understand why someone has down voted this answer.

Comment: I think that I down voted by accident. now I can not change my vote, its locked, unless the answer is edited

Comment: Have tried that, it doesn't actually add/modify the headers :/

Comment: It's complicated. Angular 2 has being under a lot of breaking changes. What is right today, may not be tomorrow.